# Cannot return referencing local variable and cannot move because its borrowed

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

I don't understand these two errors `cannot return value referencing local variable 'foo_builder'` and `cannot move out of 'foo_builder' because it is borrowed`. Here we have two structs `Foo` and `FooBuilder`, `Foo` is built by `FooBuilder` and its instance (or instances) cannot outlive FooBuilder (or thats what I'm trying to express with the code).

Then if there is a new struct called `BigChungus` that contains both, there should be no problem, right?

The fact that `Foo` cannot outlive its creator I think is properly expressed, then why rust complains that first cannot return local variable reference when the `BigChungus` now should own the `Foo` reference because it owns also `FooBuilder`?

Thanks in advance, here is the code and the [live example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a96ac8083cc59babc93143d7a74168f3):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<'r> {
    _marker: PhantomData<&'r ()>,
}

struct FooBuilder;

impl FooBuilder {
    fn create_foo(&self) -> Foo {
        Foo { _marker: PhantomData }
    }
}

struct BigChungus<'a> {
    foo: Foo<'a>,
    foo_builder: FooBuilder
}

impl<'a> BigChungus<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let foo_builder = FooBuilder;
        let foo = foo_builder.create_foo();
        Self {
            foo,
            foo_builder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foo` *borrows* from `foo_builder`.  Because `foo_builder` is borrowed, it can’t be (mutated or) moved into `BigChungus`—and, even if it could, the resulting `BigChungus` itself would not be able to be moved either (including being returned from the function).  In your case, it’s safe (because the “borrow” is not of any actual memory); but in the general case, such moves could cause dangling references and undefined behaviour.  Why do you need to limit `Foo` like this?  Perhaps there’s a better way of solving your actual problem.

Comment: It's a library that force me to do this, any idea to bypass this issue?

Even if its borrowed, it should stop in the line it gets borrowed, doesn't?, foo does not borrow from `FooBuilder` anything, just takes its lifetime.

Comment: `foo_builder` is still borrowed, just none of its memory is actually referenced—but that doesn't make any difference to the borrow-checker.  Can you share more about the library that's "forcing you to do this"?  Perhaps we can help to solve the problem a different way.

Comment: It's sdl2, it forces the usage of `TextureCreator` for the creation of `Textures`, and they created ones cannot outlive its creator. I was trying to encapsulate the `TextureCreator` and other struct that contain `Textures` created by him but was impossible because of this error

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/Rust-SDL2/rust-sdl2/issues/788

Comment: I’d just note that, unlike `Foo` in the question, `sdl2::render::Texture` also contains a raw pointer—and without knowing anything about SDL2 and its expected invariants, one imagines from the borrow that `Texture` expects to be able to dereference that pointer and reach memory controlled by the `TextureCreator`.  If so, then moving the `TextureCreator` could violate that invariant, leaving the pointer dangling and causing undefined behaviour.  Hence the borrow-checker is very much doing its job by preventing such a self-referential struct.